# Semi Transparent HDPE Bottle

Tags: materials

I am looking to create a model of a 1 litre semi-transparent HDPE bottle, containing a blue liquid. I have tried many tutorials to create a material that is semi-transparent and matte in texture, but I cannot get the material to be semi-tranparent.

[image]

I found a model that had a material that matched what I wanted. I copied the nodes into my model, but the material is different when rendered.

I am new to blender, so if there is any more infomation that you need please let me know.

This is the model with the default material.

[image]

This is the model with the material given above.

[image]

An help would be greatly appreciated.

[Blender File on Github](https://github.com/MrRBM97/BlenderStackExchange)

Comment: are you using cycles or Eevee for render? Because way I understand what you want to say is that it should be white? and render is black? Then it may be because you are using Eevee and forgot to enable some settings for transparency in material settings, Could you share that bottle with us here as a file? that texture as well, or pack it into Blender file, press F3 and type "pack all into .blend" and select option from there

Comment: To extend, please check your render settings, if you are using Eevee go to Screen space reflection, enable it and enable refraction as well, go to material settings and there is Screen space refraction option as well with depth, enable this option and if your bottle is only 1 sided (and not solidified) change depth to something like 0.1)... did it help?

Comment: I have tried both eevee and cycles. Yes the object should be white, but it would also be semi-transparent. I will pack the model now and post it.

Comment: @MikoCG I have added a link to a github repo with the file in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material you are using for your bottle is far more complicated than it needs to be.  Use a simple Principled Shader and set *Transmission* and *Transmission Roughness* to appropriate values:

[image: Simple transparent Principled shader]

If you want to tint the bottle, set the tint in the base color.  Here's what your scene looks like in Render Preview mode with full transmission:

[image: rendered bottle]

You might want to reconsider your lighting, and possibly use the compositor's noise reduction.